# LINQ Comparing Entities' Property to String Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using MVC and I have my entity model class which has a string property "type". My get method returns an array of strings to the post called `objTypes[]` from a `MultiSelectList`.

What I would like to do is a LINQ query to my db to query back only the objs that have type equal to one of the strings in the array. Similar to this:

```
objs = objs.Where(o => o.type == ("any of objType elements"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) method. Simply use:

```
var filteredObjs = objs.Where(o => objTypes.Contains(o.type));)
```

Comment: I first have var objs = db.OBjs; //to get all the objects  
then I have objs = objs.Where(o => objTypes.Contains(o.type));  
and I am getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Obj> to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.Obj>

Comment: I didn't mean to send yet, I have updated it. Thank you

Comment: I can cast as (DbSet<Obj>), however is this the correct way to do this? I just want to return a filtered list of objs to my view. And I will keep filtering like this until all the User specified filters have been achieved.

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out. Thank you for your help and your time

Comment: Try to assign the filtered object to another variable. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this..

```
var objTypes = db.OBjs.select(a=>a.type).ToList();
var result = objs.Where(o => objTypes.Contains(o.type));
```